# How to narrow the type of a variable to the type of an union

Tags: typescript

What I want to do is like codes below.

```
declare global {
    interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
        includes(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): searchElement is T;
    }
}

// ReadonlyArray<"xy" | "x" | "y" | "">
const options = ["xy", "x", "y", ""] as const;

let option: typeof options[number];

const input = htmlElement.getAttribute("foo") ?? "";
if (!options.includes(input)) {
    throw new TypeError();
}

/**
 * Below code throws this error message
 * Type 'string & T' is not assignable to type '"" | "xy" | "x" | "y"'.
 * Type 'string & T' is not assignable to type '"y"'.ts(2322)
 */
option = input;
```

Why does `options.includes(str)` not narrow the type of `input` to `"xy" | "x" | "y" | ""` when the function `includes` is redefined to return `input` is `"xy" | "x" | "y" | ""`?

Comment: pls share reproducable example. `getString` ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I just updated the part. Sorry for the insufficient information.

Comment: You get an error earlier than that, though, don't you? On the `includes`? Because `input` is type `string` but `options` is of type `("xy" | "x | "y" | "")[]`.

Comment: `includes(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): searchElement is T;` is not a very useful signature for a user-defined type guard; if `searchElement` isn't of type `T` then it's not a valid argument in the first place, since its type annotation is `T`. Also if you are using `includes` as a type guard like this, you should forbid the `fromIndex` parameter (for hopefully obvious reasons).

Comment: ^^ ...which makes it incompatible with the standard `includes`, so really best to just make your own function: https://tsplay.dev/wXkOoW

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, but I can pass that by casting it to `any`. My concern is narrowing the type of `input` to the type of the values of tuple `options`.

Comment: @kaya3 yeah you're right on that point, but I'd appreciate if you focus on a way to narrow the type of `input` :)

Comment: I agree with T.J Crowder, it is better to avoid changing global type definitions. It will impact your codebase. Sometimes the simplest solutions is the better one

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use such kind of typeguards (throwing an error) you should use TypeScript [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

```js
// ReadonlyArray<"xy" | "x" | "y" | "">
const options = ["xy", "x", "y", ""] as const;

let option: typeof options[number];

declare var htmlElement: HTMLDivElement

function assert(input: any): asserts input is (typeof options)[number] {
    if (!options.includes(input)) {
        throw new TypeError();
    }
}

const handleInput = () => {
    // input is string
    const input = htmlElement.getAttribute("foo") ?? "";
    assert(input)
    // input is "" | "xy" | "x" | "y"
    option = input;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDD0oAgJQUwQwCYHsB2AbAngQQE47hgDwBEAHhsRAD4RmU3EXW3EB8wAxqgM4AuESAA68AljwgBeCAG0yFADS1SxRYxUsAuhDjcIXFHwDcINDH5DRqAFwReGQTCQAzAcLEHpKAK4BbAEYwOBrGwAgwHGhwODAQAG5REAAWvD5oAKKmPjAovDYAEgAqALIAMgAiIrEZMFk5IE5eKByWKNrc3IG8ABQiKIJeudooGACUNjodOLy6vf38Irpddg7Ori3cI56%20AUEQAN7AEEcQIi5dAIQW7twAdL0RXmHcPX0DIyP7h8ffvIk4SAB3CAoGBAgr2GBpPBIHBdEbGb4AX2AyM4PH4iTgKAQpgAkq9%20FI4ZJWJ9vuATgSTro%20DhegBzL5HfR8SlzSRJFLpTLZXg3elmLC8Xh0vwDGBdYhOJBIYgfAD88pYCOOE06LzmIyZEApswG1JYzDk9CUJrU2quqA5et4xmRQA)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think the type of the first parameter of `includes` would bother the type narrowing smoothly. As comments on the question said, you can make it if you make a custom includes-like function whose first parameter is type of `any`.

```
declare global {
    interface ProtectedArray<T> {
        contains(e: any, from?: number): e is T;
    }

    interface Array<T> extends ProtectedArray<T> {
    }

    interface ReadonlyArray<T> extends ProtectedArray<T> {
    }
}
Array.prototype.contains = function (e, from): e is any {
    // you can define your return logic instead of below.
    return this.includes(e, from);
};
```

But I wish I could resolve it just by modifying the return type of `includes` of `Array`